# How to show parent button from JavaScript after it's hidden

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

This is probably an obvious mistake on my part.  I have a C# page that has a button that when clicked opens a calendar (ASP classic) in an iFrame.  That calendar is passed the ClientID of the button as *AddToCartButton* and uses this line:

```
lo("parent.document.getElementById('" & AddToCartButton & "').style.display = 'none';")
```

(*lo* is a *Response.Write* type function and simply outputs the text to the page.)

to hide the button when the calendar appears.  After the user selects a date the calendar uses a similar line to put the date into my C# textbox:

```
lo("parent.document.getElementById('" & PostBackField & "').value = '" & Replace(CurrentDate,":00 "," ") & "';")
```

This all works great but when I try to turn the button back on with:

```
lo("parent.document.getElementById('" & AddToCartButton & "').style.display = '';")
```

nothing happens.  I have also tried 'inline' with similar non-results.  Does anyone have an idea from what I've written here what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If it is not a programming error then I suppose it could be that the button is set to show but there is no screen refresh so it doesn't appear... but I'm grasping at straws. I'm pretty new to web programming even though I've been programming for three decades.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand why you pass the code to lo() as a string on that last line. Can't you just execute it directly in the page with the calendar when the user selects the date?

Comment: I can't because that field is used by the parent page (c#) in a storefront package we are using.  The calendar is one we wrote to talk to another reservation system.  The date has to be readable by the parent as a textbox and not just for display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using Visibility instead of display, but I can't see why your code isn't working with the display.

```
lo("parent.document.getElementById('" & AddToCartButton & "').style.visibility = 'hidden';")
```

and then

```
lo("parent.document.getElementById('" & AddToCartButton & "').style.visibility ='visible'
```

Setting the display to hidden removes the item from the flow, where visibility keeps the item in place, and just hides it, which I think is what you want.

Here is a good [article](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13638) explaining the differences.

Here is a quick sample I threw together.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function show_button()
    {
       document.getElementById("targetBtn").style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    function hide_button()
    {
       document.getElementById("targetBtn").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    function remove_button()
    {
       document.getElementById("targetBtn").style.display = 'none';
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input id="targetBtn" type="button" value="Button to Hide/Show" />
    <input type="button" onclick="show_button()" value="Show Button" />
    <input type="button" onclick="hide_button()" value="Hide Button" />
    <input type="button" onclick="remove_button()" value="Remove Button" />

    </body>
    </html>
```

If you run this example, click the show and hide buttons. You'll notice how they keep there place on the page.  Click the remove button, and they will all shift to the left.

Comment: Thanks and you are right, that is what I want to do.  I'll check into it today.  I used display because that's what I found searching for my task in Google... but they are mostly javascript solution sites and don't take .NET into account.  I'm still new to this so I ran with it :)

Comment: This is a much better way to do what I wanted.  Thanks for taking the time to go into detail and teach me something new!

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)? Try using it and see if it helps you debug the problem. You can set a breakpoint in the iframe window's code that executes the line in question and see what's happening. There, I would try to set `parent.document.getElementById('" & AddToCartButton & "')` to a variable and see what you get.

Comment: Something is going on other than what you've shown us. I just ran this code fine and was able to hide and show controls from my iFrame window no problem. Hoping firebug can help you out.

Comment: +1 for getting me to look in other code for the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: @Deverill awesome! hope you can figure it out, gl~